How to install Autodesk FBX SDK Pyhton in Blender?
I wanted to know how to edit and load FBX information in Blender after output.
It turns out that I can do this to some extent by installing Autodesk's FBX SDK Python in Blender.
My ultimate goal is to change the direction of the bones, but I haven't gotten to that stage yet.
In answer, I would like to share a description of how to install the SDK in Blender.

Before installing, note all the starting points!
The PythonSDK basically works only with Python version 3.10!
The conditions below are valid only for blender that meets these conditions.
Please check the Python version in the console before installing.

Download and install FBX SDK
Download the FBX SDK Python from the Autodisc site.
https://aps.autodesk.com/developer/overview/fbx-sdk

Install.
Then,
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX\FBX Python SDK\2020.3.7
of the standalone installation module in the
fbx-2020.3.7-cp310-none-win_amd64.whl
It can be seen that there are

Throw this into the folder where the Blender EXE file is located.

Execute the following script.
import sys, subprocess

python_path = sys.executable
module_name="fbx-2020.3.7-cp310-none-win_amd64.whl"
subprocess.call([python_path, '-m', 'pip', 'install', module_name])

The fbx module should be installed successfully.

I will check it in the console.
>>> import fbx
>>> fbx.

You can see that it is installed successfully.

Implementation of sample programs.
The sample programs are in the Autodisk folder.
The sample programs can be found in the AutoDisk folder.
There are a variety of samples,
Here we will use DisplayCommon.py.

Throw this into Blender's modules folder
。
We are ready to go! Let's run the test script that recognizes the bone information.
The path of body.fbx can be any location.
import fbx
# 列挙型の定義

from DisplayCommon import *
from fbx import FbxSkeleton
from fbx import FbxNodeAttribute
def display(pNode):
    objtype=None
    if pNode.GetNodeAttribute() == None:
        print("NULL Node Attribute\n")
        objtype="NULL"

    else:
        lAttributeType = (pNode.GetNodeAttribute().GetAttributeType())

        if lAttributeType == FbxNodeAttribute.EType.eMarker:
            print("###type : eMarker")
            objtype="eMarker"
        elif lAttributeType == FbxNodeAttribute.EType.eSkeleton:
            print("###type : eSkeleton")
            objtype="eSkeleton"

        elif lAttributeType == FbxNodeAttribute.EType.eMesh:
            print("###type : eMesh")
            objtype="eMesh"

        elif lAttributeType == FbxNodeAttribute.EType.eNurbs:
            print("###type : eNurbs")
            objtype="eNurbs"

        elif lAttributeType == FbxNodeAttribute.EType.ePatch:
            print("###type : ePatch")
            objtype="ePatch"

        elif lAttributeType == FbxNodeAttribute.EType.eCamera:
            print("###type : eCamera")
            objtype="eCamera"

        elif lAttributeType == FbxNodeAttribute.EType.eLight:
            print("###type : eLight")
            objtype="eLight"

    return objtype


def DisplaySkeleton(pNode):
    objtype=display(pNode)
    lSkeleton = pNode.GetNodeAttribute()
    if objtype=="eSkeleton":
        DisplayString("Skeleton Name: ", pNode.GetName())

        lSkeletonTypes = [ "Root", "Limb", "Limb Node", "Effector" ]

        DisplayString("    Type: ", lSkeletonTypes[lSkeleton.GetSkeletonType().value])

        if lSkeleton.GetSkeletonType() == FbxSkeleton.EType.eLimb:
            DisplayDouble("    Limb Length: ", lSkeleton.LimbLength.Get())
        elif lSkeleton.GetSkeletonType() == FbxSkeleton.EType.eLimbNode:
            DisplayDouble("    Limb Node Size: ", lSkeleton.Size.Get())
        elif lSkeleton.GetSkeletonType() == FbxSkeleton.EType.eRoot:
            DisplayDouble("    Limb Root Size: ", lSkeleton.Size.Get())

        DisplayColor("    Color: ", lSkeleton.GetLimbNodeColor())
        DisplayColor("    Color: ", lSkeleton.GetLimbNodeColor())


   
        print("LimbLength:", lSkeleton.GetLimbLengthDefaultValue())
        # print("Bone Direction:", bone_direction)

    else:
        pass



    

def process_node_hierarchy(node):
    DisplaySkeleton(node)
    for i in range(node.GetChildCount()):
        process_node_hierarchy(node.GetChild(i))

def main():
    # FBXマネージャーの作成
    fbx_manager = fbx.FbxManager.Create()
    if not fbx_manager:
        print("Error: Unable to create FBX manager!")
        return

    # FBXインポーターの作成
    fbx_importer = fbx.FbxImporter.Create(fbx_manager, "")

    # FBXファイルを読み込む
    if not fbx_importer.Initialize("body.fbx"):
        print("Error: Unable to initialize FBX importer!")
        return

    # ノードを取得する
    fbx_scene = fbx.FbxScene.Create(fbx_manager, "MyScene")
    fbx_importer.Import(fbx_scene)

    root_node = fbx_scene.GetRootNode()
    if root_node:
        print("Node and Attribute types:")
        process_node_hierarchy(root_node)

    # インポーターを解放する
    fbx_importer.Destroy()

    # FBXマネージャーを解放する
    fbx_manager.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I found that it is running successfully.
Thank you for your hard work.

Exploring sample files

how to load in Blender?

FbxCommon.py follows the format ascii by default.
This is useful to see what's in the FBX file when it's through an editor, though,
When loaded in Blender, it causes a bug.
            # if "ascii" in lDesc:
            #     pFileFormat = lFormatIndex
            #     break

By commenting out,
Blender can also read the file successfully.


about the file paths in Sample 3

Triangle.mcx
Triangle.xml
The bug occurs at the output destination of
lFPCAbsoluteDirectory  = path
with an appropriate folder name,
The output was generated.


